# Problems adding a DelegateControl to the BlackBand.Master in MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I have a custom feature which adds a few controls into the AdditionalPageHead DelegateControl.  This works fine on any sites which use our default.master.  However the project requires the use of a publishing site which has a master page derived from BlackBand.master (which does not have the AdditionalPageHead DelegateControl included), so I made a copy of the master page from the master page gallery on the appropriate site collection and then modified it to include the following line:

```
<SharePoint:DelegateControl 
    ID="DelegateControl1" 
    runat="server" 
    ControlId="AdditionalPageHead" 
    AllowMultipleControls="true"/>
```

This should therefore include this DelegateControl within all pages using this master page.  However when this is uploaded as a new version of BlackBand.master and approved as such, all the pages in the site that use it get a 404 error as if they no longer exist.  If I restore the previous version of the master page then everything return to normal.

Help is appreciated as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I was approaching the solution to my problem incorrectly.

To fix this I opened SharePoint designer at my site collection root and clicked on _catalogs/masterpage.  Then I made a copy of BlackBand.master in the masterpage catalog.  Opened it and added my line of code.  Saved it and then set it as my default and custom master page (to ensure that it applied to any straight up web part pages as well as layout pages).

This worked without a problem.